# saving rosparams

Tags: rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to save rosparams.
I can use use setParam on a running Node to set params.
But if i record the Node with rosbag and play it, then i cant see my setted param in the rosparam list.
I saw somewhere that i can use YAML for that, but i need a good tutorial for this.
I know that roslaunch helps to set params, but i dont know where to start for all these thing.
I never used roslaunch.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10059/saving-rosparams/) by [bunower](https://answers.ros.org/users/479/bunower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-05-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosparam command-line tool will let you save and restore parameters.  The documentation is here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosparam

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [smihael](https://answers.ros.org/users/23102/smihael/) on 2015-08-18**:
is there any way to do it programatically?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-04-10**:\

1. Commandline tools are programs that can be easilly integrated into your application. 2) If you mean "programatically" by language client APIs, you can use [`dump_params` in Python API](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/rosparam/html/rosparam-pysrc.html#dump_params).